# unable to open file for reading error in laravel

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

i have a form in laravel which sends the data to email and database, i am trying to store the image from form in public folder, then the following error happened

> Unable to open file for reading [/hermes/walnaweb08a/b1307/as.book/TEIA/storage/app/public/1562913994bannernew.jpg]

the error is occured in the following code for swiftmailer

```html
 private function getReadHandle()
    {
        if (!isset($this->reader)) {
            $pointer = @fopen($this->path, 'rb');
            if (!$pointer) {
                throw new Swift_IoException('Unable to open file for reading ['.$this->path.']');
            }
            $this->reader = $pointer;
            if (0 != $this->offset) {
                $this->getReadStreamSeekableStatus();
                $this->seekReadStreamToPosition($this->offset);
            }
        }
 
        return $this->reader;
    }
```

this is my sendmail.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use App\Register;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
   public $sub;
    public $msg;
    public $phot;
    public $rec;
    public $sig;
    public function __construct($subject,$message,$photo,$recipt,$sign)
    {
       $this->sub = $subject;
       $this->msg = $message;
       $this->phot = $photo;
       $this->rec = $recipt;
       $this->sig = $sign;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        
       $b_subject = $this->sub;
        $b_message = $this->msg;
        $reg = Register::where('id',$b_message)->first();
        $b_phot = $this->phot;
        $b_phot = $this->phot;
        $recipt = $this->rec;
        $sign = $this->sig;
        return $this->view('mail.sendmail', compact("reg","b_phot","sign","recipt"))->subject($b_subject);
    }
}
```

the image is stored in the folder and data is sent to database, but the problem is this error occurs and the data is not sent to mail. can anyone please tell what coul be the problem

Comment: Check the file and folder permission

Comment: @CerlinBoss i am new to this, can you please tell me how to check

Comment: navigate to the folder in terminal and run `ls -al` (in mac and linux) and see if the file is readable or search online to find this

Comment: @CerlinBoss the file is in the server

Comment: Your code is also in the server so u must be having access to it. Open your local terminal and ssh into the server or read about all those things first before trying.

Comment: @CerlinBoss the folder permision is readonly

Comment: The file might not be existing in the mentioned location at the time of reading

Comment: just change the permissions of your folder like this: `sudo chmod -R 777 yourfoldername`